# Java Match string with optional hyphen

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a series of string thats looks like this:

```
item1        = "some value"
item2        = "some value"
```

I have some strings, though, that look like this:

```
item-one        = "some new value"
item-two        = "some new value"
```

I am trying to parse it using regular expressions, but I can't get it to match the optional hyphen.

Here is my regex string:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+[-]?)\\w+?\\s+=\\s+\"(.*)\"");
 Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
 m.find();

 String option = m.group(1);
 String value  = m.group(2);
```

May someone please tell me what I could be doing wrong.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that main reason of your problem is that you are expecting `w+?` to make `w+` optional, where in reality it will make `+` quantifier [reluctant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) so regex will still try to find at least one or more `\\w` here, consuming last character from `^(\\w+`.

Maybe try this way

```
Pattern.compile("^(\\w+(?:-\\w+)?)\\s+=\\s+\"(.*?)\"");
```

- in `(\\w+(?:-\\w+)?)` -> `(?:-\\w+)` part will create non-capturing group (regex wont count it as group so `(.*?)` will be group(2) even if this part will exist) and `?` after it will make this part optional.
- in `\"(.*?)\"` `*?` is [reluctant quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) which will make regex to look for minimal match that exist between quotation marks.

**[Demo](http://ideone.com/0Hqe1q)**

Comment: This is the best answer so far.  The name must *start* with one or more word characters, and if there's a hyphen it must be *followed* by one or more word characters.

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work for you:

```
^\w[\w-]*(?<=\w)\s*=\s*\"([^"]*)\"
```

In Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\w[\\w-]*(?<=\\w)\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"");
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/0CvByDnj5H

Comment: This regex would allow `------="foo"`. I'm pretty sure that is not OK

Comment: Still not right.  The name has to start with a word character now, but it can still end with a hyphen and/or contain multiple consecutive hyphens (e.g. `x----="foo"`).

Comment: @AlanMoore: Good point, made another edit to take care of this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have the `?` in the wrong place:

Try this regex:

```
^((\\w+-)?\\w+)\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"
```

But use groups 1 and 3.

I've cleaned up the regex a bit too

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

`([\w\-]+)\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"`

With extra backslashes for Java:

`([\\w\\-]+)\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]*)\"`

If you expect other symbols to start appearing in the variable name, you could make it a character class like `[^=\s]` to accept any characters not = or whitespace, for example.